# How do I weight my rate by sample size (in Datadog)?

Tags: metrics, datadog

So I have an ongoing metric of events. They are either tagged as success or fail. So I have 3 numbers; failed, completed, total. This is easily illustrated (in Datadog) using a stacked bar graph like so:

[image]

So the dark part are the failures. And by looking at the y scale and the dashed red line for scale, this easily tells a human if the rate is a problem and significant. Which to mean means that I have a failure rate in excess of 60%, over at least some time (10 minutes?) and that there are enough events in this period to consider the rate exceptional.

So I am looking for some sort of formula that starts with: failures divided by total (giving me a score between 0 and 1) and then multiplies this somehow again with the total and some thresholds that I decide means that the total is high enough for me to get an automated alert.

For extra credit, here is the actual Datadog metric that I am trying to get to work:

> (sum:event{status:fail}.rollup(sum, 300) / sum:event{}.rollup(sum,
>   300))

And I am watching for 15 minutes and alert of score above 0.75. But I am not sure about sum, count, avg, rollup or count. And ofc this alert will send me mail during the night when the total events goes low enough to were a high failure rate isn't proof of any problem.